# Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, deployment, atmosphere, grizzly

I'm running into an issue where my deployable jar hits an exception that doesn't happen when I run this locally in IntelliJ.

**Exception:**

```
Receiving an event {id=2, socket=0c317829-69bf-43d6-b598-7c0c550635bb, type=getDashboard, data={workstationUuid=ddec1caa-a97f-4922-833f-632da07ffc11}, reply=true}
Firing getDashboard event to Socket#0c317829-69bf-43d6-b598-7c0c550635bb
Failed invoking AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport()
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2502)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:2468)
        at com.github.flowersinthesand.portal.support.DefaultDispatcher$DefaultHandler$DataParam.resolve(DefaultDispatcher.java:270)
        at com.github.flowersinthesand.portal.support.DefaultDispatcher$DefaultHandler.handle(DefaultDispatcher.java:204)
        at com.github.flowersinthesand.portal.support.DefaultDispatcher.fire(DefaultDispatcher.java:107)
        at com.github.flowersinthesand.portal.support.AbstractSocketFactory.fire(AbstractSocketFactory.java:73)
        at com.github.flowersinthesand.portal.atmosphere.AtmosphereSocketFactory.onRequest(AtmosphereSocketFactory.java:75)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:256)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:166)
        at org.atmosphere.container.Grizzly2WebSocketSupport.service(Grizzly2WebSocketSupport.java:75)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1342)
        at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:219)
        at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor$2.run(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:183)
        at org.atmosphere.util.VoidExecutorService.execute(VoidExecutorService.java:101)
        at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:178)
        at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.invokeWebSocketProtocol(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:167)
        at org.atmosphere.container.Grizzly2WebSocketSupport$Grizzly2WebSocketApplication.onMessage(Grizzly2WebSocketSupport.java:171)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.DefaultWebSocket.onMessage(DefaultWebSocket.java:164)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.frametypes.TextFrameType.respond(TextFrameType.java:70)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.DataFrame.respond(DataFrame.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketFilter.handleRead(WebSocketFilter.java:221)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:134)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:78)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:770)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:551)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:531)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:781)
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:219)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:44)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:13)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2704)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1315)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2498)
        ... 34 more
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] Status 500 Message Server Error
```

**Socket Handler**

I believe the exception is occurring when the JSON is parsed into a WorkstationRequest object because of the below item.  This is the socket handler:

```
@On
@Reply
@JsonView({Views.WorkstationView.class})
public WorkstationDashboard getDashboard(@Data WorkstationRequest request) {
    return new WorkstationDashboard(request.getWorkstation());
}
```

The object the socket handler maps to:

```
public class WorkstationRequest {

    /* Class to instantiate if this workstation does not already exist */
    private Class<? extends Workstation> workstationClass;

    private WorkflowProcess workflowProcess;

    private PhysicalWorkstation workstation;

    WorkstationService workstationService;

    /**
     * @param workstationClass Required so when jackson maps the UUID we can auto fetch the class
     */
    public WorkstationRequest(Class<? extends Workstation> workstationClass) {
        this.workstationClass = workstationClass;
        workstationService = (WorkstationService) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("workstationService");
    }

    /* Set the workstation based on UUID.  Will register the workstation if it's new */
    @JsonProperty("workstationUuid")
    public void setWorkstation(String workstationUUID) {
        workstation = (PhysicalWorkstation)WorkstationService.getWorkstation(workstationUUID);

        //setup new workstation
        if (workstation == null) {
            WorkstationEntity workstationEntity = workstationService.findByUUID(workstationUUID);
            workstation = (PhysicalWorkstation)Workstation.factory(workstationEntity, workstationClass);

            //register with queue
            WorkflowProcessService.getWorkflowProcess(workstation).registerWorkstation(workstation);
        }
    }

    public PhysicalWorkstation getWorkstation() {
        return workstation;
    }
}
```

The JSON being mapped:

```
{"id":2,"socket":"0c317829-69bf-43d6-b598-7c0c550635bb","type":"getDashboard","data":{"workstationUuid":"ddec1caa-a97f-4922-833f-632da07ffc11"},"reply":true}
```

**WorkstationDashboard.java**

```
public class WorkstationDashboard {
    private HashMap<String, Object> queue = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    private LinkedBlockingDeque<JobSetEntity> currentWork;

    public WorkstationDashboard() {
        queue.put("size", 0);
    }

    public WorkstationDashboard(Workstation workstation) {
        fromWorkstation(workstation);
    }

    /* Populate dashboard data from a workstation */
    public void fromWorkstation(Workstation workstation) {
        WorkflowProcess workflowProcess = WorkflowProcessService.getWorkflowProcess(workstation);

        setCurrentWork(workstation.getCurrentWork());
        setQueueSize(workflowProcess.getQueue().size());
    }

    public void setQueueSize(Integer queueSize) {
        queue.put("size", queueSize);
    }

    public HashMap<String, Object> getQueue() {
        return queue;
    }

    public LinkedBlockingDeque<JobSetEntity> getCurrentWork() {
        return currentWork;
    }

    public void setCurrentWork(LinkedBlockingDeque<JobSetEntity> currentWork) {
        this.currentWork = currentWork;
    }
}
```

I'm at quite a loss as to how to begin debugging this.  The stack trace never touches my application.  I'm using `Maven -> Package` to deploy my .jar and executing it with `java -jar /path-to-jar.jar`

**Update:** To prevent this question from being incredibly long, I've included my pom.xml here: http://pastebin.com/1ZUtKCfE.  I believe this is a dependency issue since the error only occurs on my deployable jar and not on my local PC.

Answer (score 95):

You're mapping this JSON

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "socket": "0c317829-69bf-43d6-b598-7c0c550635bb",
    "type": "getDashboard",
    "data": {
        "workstationUuid": "ddec1caa-a97f-4922-833f-632da07ffc11"
    },
    "reply": true
}
```

that contains an element named `data` that has a JSON object as its value. You are trying to deserialize the element named `workstationUuid` from that JSON object into this setter.

```
@JsonProperty("workstationUuid")
public void setWorkstation(String workstationUUID) {
```

This won't work directly because Jackson sees a JSON_OBJECT, not a String.

Try creating a class `Data`

```
public class Data { // the name doesn't matter 
    @JsonProperty("workstationUuid")
    private String workstationUuid;
    // getter and setter
}
```

the switch up your method

```
@JsonProperty("data")
public void setWorkstation(Data data) {
    // use getter to retrieve it
```

Comment: I failed to describe this in detail, but the Socket library I'm using maps the `data` field in that array to my object via `public WorkstationDashboard getDashboard(@Data WorkstationRequest request) {`.  It calls `getDashboard()` because of the `type` in that JSON, then maps `data`.

I could be wrong, since I don't really know what's going on.  But since this all works locally on my PC and breaks when I deploy my application via a .jar it seems like it's some kind of dependency issue.  My pom is here: http://pastebin.com/1ZUtKCfE

Comment: @Webnet Is `@Data` a custom annotation that binds the `data` field from the JSON? You'll have to backtrack to see how it generates the `WorkstationRequest` argument.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, if my data keeps changing, I mean I would not be sure that how many values will `data` field contain. Is there any work around? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053106/how-to-get-plain-json-data-in-jersey-rest-implementation/39053141#39053141

Comment: @theGamblerRises If you have absolutely no idea what type will be associated with it, you can use the generic JSON type for the JSON library you are using. With Jackson, that is `JsonNode`. This couples your code to Jackson however and doesn't make it easy to then use that value.

Answer (score 45):

If you do not want to define a separate class for nested json , Defining nested json object as JsonNode should work ,for example :

```
{"id":2,"socket":"0c317829-69bf-43d6-b598-7c0c550635bb","type":"getDashboard","data":{"workstationUuid":"ddec1caa-a97f-4922-833f-632da07ffc11"},"reply":true}

@JsonProperty("data")
    private JsonNode data;
```

Comment: I didn't need to use the @JsonProperty annotation - from my understanding it's only required where the name in the JSON is different from the attribute name in the Object.

Comment: If you don't want to use 'JsonNode' you can define a separate class for '"data":{..}' array and use that class name instead of 'JsonNode'.

Answer (score 30):

Data content is so variable, I think the best form is to define it as "ObjectNode" and next create his own class to parse:

Finally:

private ObjectNode data;

Comment: You saved my long chase for this. My `data` field can have any JSON inside, so I cannot map it with some POJO. I was searching for some solution which can hold only JSON value. Thank you so much. Just to double check, is there any side-effect or drawbacks of using it?

Answer (score 7):

To solve this(in case that your data object can have any undefined json or there is no POJO defined for data), simply use [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) to take data as input

```
private JsonNode data;
```

Then you can use [jsonpath dependency](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/latest/index.html) to access the values inside data.

To fetch uuid from this json

```
  "data": {
    "workStation": {
        {
          "uuid": "2",
          "Title": "Graduation day party"              
        }
    }
    "code": 200
  }
```

Use [JsonContext](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.2.0/com/jayway/jsonpath/internal/JsonContext.html) from JsonPath library to read via JsonPath

```
DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonContext.createContext(data);
String uuid = jsonContext.read("workStation.uuid");
```

DocumentContext read method takes the path in json as attribute

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the problem using Jackson library. Prints are called out of Main class and all POJO classes are created. Here is the code snippets.

**MainClass.java**

```
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, 
       JsonMappingException, IOException {

String jsonStr = "{\r\n" + "    \"id\": 2,\r\n" + " \"socket\": \"0c317829-69bf- 
             43d6-b598-7c0c550635bb\",\r\n"
            + " \"type\": \"getDashboard\",\r\n" + "    \"data\": {\r\n"
            + "     \"workstationUuid\": \"ddec1caa-a97f-4922-833f- 
            632da07ffc11\"\r\n" + " },\r\n"
            + " \"reply\": true\r\n" + "}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    MyPojo details = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, MyPojo.class);

    System.out.println("Value for getFirstName is: " + details.getId());
    System.out.println("Value for getLastName  is: " + details.getSocket());
    System.out.println("Value for getChildren is: " + 
      details.getData().getWorkstationUuid());
    System.out.println("Value for getChildren is: " + details.getReply());

}
```

**MyPojo.java**

```
public class MyPojo {
    private String id;

    private Data data;

    private String reply;

    private String socket;

    private String type;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getReply() {
        return reply;
    }

    public void setReply(String reply) {
        this.reply = reply;
    }

    public String getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public void setSocket(String socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    } 
}
```

**Data.java**

```
public class Data {
    private String workstationUuid;

    public String getWorkstationUuid() {
        return workstationUuid;
    }

    public void setWorkstationUuid(String workstationUuid) {
        this.workstationUuid = workstationUuid;
    }   
}
```

**RESULTS:**

```
Value for getFirstName is: 2
Value for getLastName  is: 0c317829-69bf-43d6-b598-7c0c550635bb
Value for getChildren is: ddec1caa-a97f-4922-833f-632da07ffc11
Value for getChildren is: true
```

Answer (score 1):

This way I solved my problem. Hope it helps others.
In my case I created a class, a field, their getter & setter and then provide the object instead of string.

**Use this**

```
public static class EncryptedData {
    private String encryptedData;

    public String getEncryptedData() {
        return encryptedData;
    }

    public void setEncryptedData(String encryptedData) {
        this.encryptedData = encryptedData;
    }
}

@PutMapping(value = MY_IP_ADDRESS)
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse> updateMyIpAddress(@RequestBody final EncryptedData encryptedData) {
    try {
        Path path = Paths.get(PUBLIC_KEY);
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(base64.decode(bytes));
        PrivateKey privateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance(CRYPTO_ALGO_RSA).generatePrivate(ks);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CRYPTO_ALGO_RSA);
        cipher.init(Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY, privateKey);
        String decryptedData = new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedData.getEncryptedData().getBytes()));
        String[] dataArray = decryptedData.split("|");


        Method updateIp = Class.forName("com.cuanet.client.helper").getMethod("methodName", String.class,String.class);
        updateIp.invoke(null, dataArray[0], dataArray[1]);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Unable to update ip address for encrypted data: "+encryptedData, e);
    }

    return null;
```

Instead of this

```
@PutMapping(value = MY_IP_ADDRESS)
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse> updateMyIpAddress(@RequestBody final EncryptedData encryptedData) {
    try {
        Path path = Paths.get(PUBLIC_KEY);
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(base64.decode(bytes));
        PrivateKey privateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance(CRYPTO_ALGO_RSA).generatePrivate(ks);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CRYPTO_ALGO_RSA);
        cipher.init(Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY, privateKey);
        String decryptedData = new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedData.getBytes()));
        String[] dataArray = decryptedData.split("|");


        Method updateIp = Class.forName("com.cuanet.client.helper").getMethod("methodName", String.class,String.class);
        updateIp.invoke(null, dataArray[0], dataArray[1]);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Unable to update ip address for encrypted data: "+encryptedData, e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kotlin you might wanna try removing `data` keyword from class declaration.

```
   {
      "data": {
        "Calendar": {
          "Events": [
            {
              "ID": "1",
              "Title": "Graduation day"
            },
            {
              "ID": "2",
              "Title": "Graduation day party"              
            }
          ]
        }
      }
      "code": 200
    }
```

I had this as a JSON and my POJO class was like this :

```
class Response(code: Int, val data: Data){
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    class Data(@JsonProperty("Calendar") val calendar: Calendar) {}

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    data class Event(
        val ID: Int? = null,
        val Title: String? = null
    )

    data class Calendar(
        @JsonProperty("Events") val eventsList: ArrayList<Event>
    )
}
```

Removing `data` from `class Event` and `class Calendar` it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

These types of errors occur when we are using an incorrect Data Type for POJO variables.

Answer (score 0):

Faced Issue In : SpringBoot Application

My Controller Method definition:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endPoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ApiResponse methodName(@RequestBody String json) throws ParseException
```

Error Message :

```
HttpMessageNotReadableException - JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException
```

In my case the issue was because of configuration to limit direct string body in http calls.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
      converters.removeIf(StringHttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance);
    }
    .
    .
```

Allowing StringHttpMessageConverter.class will solve the issue.

Note: Best practice is to limit the String body in post calls