# How to get plain JSON data in jersey REST implementation?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey-2.0

If we have a POJO class, then we can map it with some incoming JSON. I am struggling to find out a way by which I can just have all plain json value inside.

For ex.

```
{
    "macro_tasks": [
        {
            "id": "cc5cee68-c1e5-4396-987b-c68559399186",
            "label": "consi-1",
            "name": "Consi 1",
            "project_id": "82d1e463-1bb1-42d3-9adc-9e0d5848d139",
            "creator_id": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "meta_data": {
                "key1": "value1",
                "key2": 321
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here `meta_data` is of JSON type which can keep changing its values inside. So I cannot map it with some POJO class.

```
public class MacroTask {

    private UUID id;
    private String label;
    private String name;

    private UUID projectId;

    private UUID creatorId;

    private String createdAt;

    private String updatedAt;

    private <some data type> meta_data;

//getter and setter
```

Is there any way to get plain JSON data and use it in code and dump into DB [we are using PostgreSQL, which supports `jsonb` type.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using Generic JSON type, Jackson's `JsonNode`. It has some drawbacks as I heard, but I am giving it a try. So far, it's working as per expectations. I will update if I face any challenge or I find any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map; like

```
private Map<String, Object> meta_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got following error

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT
```

I was using this code for json string to HasMap conversion.

```
Map map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>>(){});
```

I replaced it with.

```
Map map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>(){});
```